# Running Python DynamoDB on an EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, localhost, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I want to use DynamoDB in an EC2 instance in Python. I have tested it locally, and set up my DynamoDB resource locally by using:

```
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_ID,
     aws_secret_access_key= ACCESS_KEY, region_name='us-west-2', endpoint_url='http://localhost:8000')
```

I am wondering if, once it is running on an EC2 instance, the endpoint_url should be changed (to something different than http://localhost:8000), or if I should set up the resource in a completely different way. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, you should avoid putting credentials in your source code. This can lead to security breaches and is difficult to update Instead:

- **When running on an Amazon EC2 instance:** Assign an IAM Role to the instance. The code will automatically find credentials.
- **When running on your own system:** Store credentials in the `~.aws/credentials` file (or run `aws configure` to create the file).

If you wish to connect with DynamoDB, **leave out the endpoint parameter**. I assume that you have been using [DynamoDB Local](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.html), which runs on your own computer. To use the 'real' DynamoDB, leave out the endpoint.

Also, it is a good idea to include a region, such as:

```
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='ap-southeast-2')
```